# accessing window event data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery/javaScript and am having difficulty returning data from this function set.

The first function queries the window and performs some simple math, returning a figure.

The second function calls the first function to perform updates.

The data returned take the form [object Object] and I am having trouble accessing its value. Can anyone offer assistance - how do I successfully access the return value?

Here is the code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function restingHeight()
        {
            var height = $(this).height();
            var rheight = Math.round( height - height * 0.15 );
            //alert(rheight);
            return rheight;
        }

        function resizeUpdate(item)
        {
            var updated = $(window).resize(item);
            return updated;
        }

        </script>
```

And in the document to view the return:

```
<div id="coordination" style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;">
    Test 1: <script>document.write(restingHeight());</script></br>
    Test 2: <script>document.write(resizeUpdate(restingHeight));</script>
</div>
```

Note the alert is commented out - it displays correct values.

Comment: What is `item`? The problem is that you're returning the value from `$(window).resize(item);`. According to the [`.resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) api documentation, this function returns `jQuery` which is a superset object of the DOM object. What value are you wanting?

Comment: "item" is typically a function, for example, the function "restingHeight".

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. So I guess my next question is what are you expecting to have returned? The function? an integer? a string?, etc.

Comment: War10ck, Sorry for taking so long to reply. I'm trying to return an integer (pixel number) but I have run across this issue elsewhere when trying to return data, for example, using .change() to access the value from a select menu. Your help is appreciated greatly, and again sorry to take so long replying!

Comment: No problem buddy. That clears some things up. So from the documentation I linked to above, it shows that `.resize()` takes: (a) an event handler, or (b) event data and an event handler. I don't think the `$(window).resize(item)` will be valid. It looks like `item` is a number, not a handler. Are you possibly trying to trigger the `resize` event? I've never tried to do this, but it may work. What I think you may be looking for though is `$(window).resize(item).height();` or `$(window).resize(item).outerHeight();` (whichever works best for you). This should return you the height.